# Error Automatización ( He probado todo lo que he podido leer en la red , sin éxito)

Tags: excel, vba

Os escribo después de estar intentando solventar el problema más de 1 mes, incluso el equipo de sistemas de mi empresa está detrás de este problema.

Resulta que tengo un libro de excel ( donde se trabaja a diario ), pero ahora resulta que cuando ejecutas la macro ( no he conseguido saber que lo causa ), salta error de automatizacion sin dar ninguna tipo de mensaje ni número de error.

Es cuando se abre un formulario, si ejecuto la macro paso a paso NUNCA salta el error.
He estado mirando por todos los foros, y he probado a realizar todas las pruebas que he visto. Todo sin Exito.

Os comento la cantidad de cosas que hemos probado.

1. Distintas versiones de Excel ( 32Bits y 64 bits ), ahora estoy con Office 365 64 bits, pero en todas da el error.
2. Hemos probado con distintos NetFrameWork , también sin exito.
3. En un foro, leí que podría ser por declarar las variables como integer, ahora están todas las integer como long.
4. Se ha formateado mi equipo, e instalado todo de 0, simplemente tiene Windows 10 Pro y Office 365, también tenemos el antivirus corporativo Panda Cytomic ( Pero probando sin antivirus, idem de los mismo ).
5. He repasado el código de arriba a abajo con puntos de interrupción, en todos estos casos si ha funcionado.
6. No siempre falla, pero cuando lo hace intenta recuperar el fichero *xlsm como *xlsb , pero realmente no repara nada ( Siguen fallando ambos ).
7. Se han cambiado las políticas del antivirus, pero como os digo, sin el instalado también ocurre.
8. He incluido en la carga del formulario_initialize un detalle de errores , on error goto errores:, pero no llega a dar error en el código, cuando salta el de automatización excel se queda totalmente colgado.
9. Hemos actualizado todos los parches de Excel... nada todo igual.

Si podéis comentar que podría ser, o os habéis encontrado con algo similar, agradezco vuestra opinones.

Gracias,

Comment: Si aún no has leído [ask] **leelo**. Por favor incluye tu macro y la estructura del libro o la hoja de excel para que quienes saben puedan replicar el problema y tratar de ayudarte. En la forma actual de la pregunta sólo es posible formular **sugerencias especulativas** que seguramente sólo te servirán para aumentar el tiempo invertido en la solución.

Comment: Para dar algun tipo de solucion, hay que saber que hace... Sin el codigo que causa el error, es poco lo que podemos hacer...

Comment: El código es muy largo, mañana intentaré resumir y subir la parte más importante.

Comment: *si ejecuto la macro paso a paso NUNCA salta el error* Es posible que, dependiendo de la cantidad de información que se mueva, o el volumen de cálculos, a veces VBA ejecuta líneas de código cuando no ha terminado de resolver las anteriores.  Se soluciona la mayoría de las veces optimizando el código y con `DoEvents`. Pero sin ver tu código y el momento exacto en el que falla, imposible acertar.

Comment: Hola, Gracias por vuestras respuestas. Como os digo la cantidad de código es bastante extensa. voy a ver la forma de simplificar lo máximo. Realmente el 90% de la macro se  basa en buscar valores en varias hojas y visualizarlos en el formulario.

Comment: Empieza poniendo solamente la parte en la que salta el error, así como el error que es

Comment: Hola, No puedo pegar todo el código, me pasa de número de caracteres permitidos, cierto que es un código bastante largo. No se si es posible hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: Como se ha dicho antes, céntrate en la parte que produce el error.

Answer (score 0):

La parte que produce el error, esta en un modulo de unas 200 líneas.
Finalmente he usado otra macro anterior ( Sin las últimas modificaciones, donde estaba usando arrays y ya no tengo el error ).
Por lo visto, los arrays no se llevan muy bien con lo que estoy haciendo.

Para las proximas veces que vaya a usar arrays, pondré un control de errores y prestaré atención a como realizarlos.
Un saludo y gracias,

Answer (score 0):

Ese error lo tuve cuando en una macro, copiaba y pegaba valores en un rango:

```
Columns("B:AS").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks 
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

No entiendo por que, pero este error lo causaba una formula que tenia en la celda "AT2" de mi hoja de excel. Cambie el orden de los pasos en la macro para primero copiar y pegar, y después incluir la formula en la celda "AT2"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos